# Git merge commit with no changes removes edits to file

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-merge

A coworker and I are working on a project that uses git for source control.  This afternoon, I made several commits to a particular file, `MyFile.txt`.  I pushed my changes to our main branch (`trunk`), and my coworker merged his (unrelated) changes shortly after.  Here's a visual:

[image]

After my coworker made his merge commit (the commit above tagged as `1.0.1834`), all of my changes were gone!

I switched back to my commit (tagged as `1.0.1833`) to verify that I correctly committed my changes; I did - `MyFile.txt` had all of my changes from that afternoon.  However, if I switch to my coworker's merge commit (tagged as `1.0.1834`), `MyFile.txt` is in its original state without any of my changes.

My coworker's merge commit (`1.0.1834`) contains no changes - the "Diff" window in `gitk` is empty.  Here's another view of the commit from our GitLab site:

[image]

What happened?  Where did my changes go?  How can I prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could happen if your cowroker has done a [`git merge --ours`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).

The resulting merge commit would be identical to his previous commit HEAD.

This is the merge strategy ours:

> **the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches**. It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches.
>   Note that this is different from the `-Xours` option to the *recursive* merge strategy.